# Complex and real axis in LaTeX - graphing

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can somebody help me to make such an illustration in LaTeX, then I would be very happy! I'm new to LaTeX, but I am trying to learn how to graph different things. I tried using another code I saw in here as a base, but it really didn't seem to be working - hope that anybody can help me then!

[image]

Comment: E.g. `\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,thick]
 \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (2.5,0) node[right]{Re};
 \draw[->] (0,-0.2) -- (0,3) node[above]{Im};
 \draw[->,blue!80!black] (0,0) --
  (60:2.5) node[fill,circle,inner sep=2pt,label=above right:$a+\mathrm{i}\,b$]
 (z) {} ;
 \draw[dashed] (0,0|-z) node[left]{$b$}-- (z)
  (0,0-|z) node[below]{$a$}-- (z);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`.

Comment: Apart from a direct and detailed solution, a step-by-step tutorial may also help. The first tutorial in [doc of tikz](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf), sec. 2 is a such one.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short code with `pstricks`:

```
\documentclass[border=6pt, svgnames]{standalone}%
\usepackage{pst-plot, pst-eucl}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture*}(-1,-1)(4,4)
\psset{arrowinset=0.15, linejoin, arrows=->}
\psaxes[ticks=none, labels=none, labelsep=0.3em](0,0)(-1,-1)(3,3.5)[\text{Re},0][\text{Im},90]
\pstGeonode[PointName=0, PosAngle=-135, PointSymbol=none](0; 0){O}
\psCoordinates[linestyle=dashed, arrows=-,dotscale=0.1](2,2.5)
\uput[d](2,0){$a$}\uput[l](0,2.5){$b$}
\psset{linecolor=CornflowerBlue, linewidth=1.5pt}
\pstGeonode[PointName=a{+}bi, PosAngle=75, PointNameSep=0.8em](2,2.5){Z}
\ncline{O}{Z}%
\end{pspicture*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an even shorter code with `tikz` from [the above comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/533870/complex-and-real-axis-in-latex-graphing#comment1350102_533870), which can be compiled with any of the standard compiler (`pdflatex`, `xelatex`, `lualatex`) without any special preparations or switches. To have a partial overlap of the arrow with the dot, use `shorten` with a negative distance.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth,thick]
 \draw[->] (-0.2,0) -- (2.5,0) node[right]{Re};
 \draw[->] (0,-0.2) -- (0,3) node[above]{Im};
 \draw[->,blue!80,shorten >=-1pt] 
    (60:2.5) node[fill,circle,inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0pt,label=above right:$a+\mathrm{i}\,b$]
    (z) {} (0,0) --(z);
 \draw[dashed] (0,0|-z) node[left]{$b$}-- (z)
  (0,0-|z) node[below]{$a$}-- (z);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Like many others, I prefer to typeset the imaginary `i` upright to make it distinguishable from an index `i`.